# removing content from title bar in ext js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs

I m using ext js 6 with sencha cmd, when I use title header in ext js, it autogenerate the css class with content: 'd' like one in below screenshot in many places.

here is screenshot

[image]

Is there any way i can get rid of it i have tried Jquery following code: 
empty div from parent

```
<script>
       $('#form-1010_header-title').empty();
</script>
```

and also removing class

```
<script>
       $("div #form-1010_header-title-textEl").removeClass("x-title-text");
</script>
```

none of it work...

here is the autogenerated html code from ext js

[image]

here is css description

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are working with a commercial trial version of ExtJS.

The `ext-watermark` font, which you seem to have deleted or otherwise removed from the project, should show a reminder to buy ExtJS before you ship your commercial project.

If you have access to the full version via Sencha support portal, download it from there and run `sencha app upgrade`. If you don't have access to the full version, you can download the latest GPL version of the framework and use that; but please keep in mind that the GPL version (a) may only be used for projects licensed under GPL and (b) may contain tons of bugs that have already been resolved in the commercial version.